# Wordpress: Featured images all showing with 1px width and 1px height

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm not sure what exactly has caused this, but either after upgrading to the latest WP version or using WP.SmushIt plugin, [all my featured/thumbnail images](http://ztwealth.com/) are displaying with 1px width, and 1px height.

The regular images used inside the pages/content are fine, only those that I'm calling using `get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'carousel-thumb');` are broken.

`carousel-thumb` is just a custom size I've defined in my functions.php like `add_image_size( 'carousel-thumb', 220, 220, true ); //(cropped)`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should look for that thumbnail function in your wordpress theme function file. like add_image_size( 'carousel-thumb', 1, 1, true ), also check your CSS maybe it was forced to have that size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was able to fix the issue using [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin.

Comment: if/when that link expires or moves this answer will be absolutely useless. Consider adding an actual solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to add this code to your functions.php,

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'style_thumbsss' );
function style_thumbsss()
{   
    echo '
    <style type="text/css">
    .inside p.hide-if-no-js a img.attachment-post-thumbnail { width: 230px!important; height: 160px!important; }
    </style>';
}
```

or may need to use plugin, called "REGENERATE thumbnails" , which creates new thumbs for the uploads images, and sets them normally.